# C++ Access data member of another class

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, counter, qthread

I am creating a simple multithreading app with Qt, and I want to print the number of threads I created from a function from within the thread class (QThread).

So for example, if I create 3 threads of class T, the function T.printcount should print out "3 threads active".

I assume that I would have create a variable outside the T class (perhaps the main thread), and access from the thread class.  How would I do so?

Is it better to create a virtual static variable in class T and access that?

Other ideas?

Comment: virtual variable? what is this? virtual static, hmm. do you mean static function in class?

Comment: You could just use `static` variable for keeping number of the instances. Of course, you need to watch for race conditions (QMutex?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote: if I create 3 threads of class T, the function T.printcount should print out "3 threads active".

In this case it is better that you create a static variable inside the class and then update it with each object creation. 
You can access the static variable without the need of a function btw.

Something like: ClassName::StaticVariable

In case you are going to print a static variable of the class via a function, do not forget to make that function static.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to connect signals and slots across different threads, thanks to a mechanism called [queued connections](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum). So one option might be to connect a signal from your thread

```
signals:

    void threadCreated();
```

to some object from main thread, i.e an instance of your class ThreadCounter:

```
class ThreadCounter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int count;

public slots:
    void increaseCountVariable() {
        count++;
    }
//...
};
```

and connect them:

```
connect(myThread, &MyThread::threadCreated, myThreadCounter,
                    &ThreadCounter::increaseCountVariable);
```

from [Qt pages](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html):

> It is important to remember that a QThread object usually lives in the
>   thread where it was created, not in the thread that it manages. Note: If you interact with an object, using any technique other than queued signal/slot connections (e.g. direct function calls), then the usual multithreading precautions need to be taken.